# Serilog deconstruct child class

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, logging, serilog

**Question**

How do I configure Serilog deconstruction for a base class so that all children classes will be deconstructed in the same way?

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Destructure.ByTransforming<BaseAbstractClass>(t => 
                    new { TaskId = t.Id, JobId = t.JobId})

var childClass = new ChildClass { Id = 1, JobId = 1, SomeOtherPropertyIDoNotCareAbout = "value"};
Log.Information("{@ChildClass}", childClass )

public abstract class BaseAbstractClass
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
}

public class ChildClass: BaseAbstractClass
    {
        public string SomeOtherPropertyIDoNotCareAbout { get; set; }
    }
```

**Context**

I got the following Serilog configuration:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Destructure.ByTransforming<Task>(t => 
                    new { TaskId = t.Id, JobId = t.JobId})
```

Where the base task class is

```
public abstract class Task
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public Job Job { get; set; }
    public TaskType Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

public enum TaskType
{
    StoredProcedure
}
```

And the child class is:

```
public class StoredProcedure : Task
{
    public string ServerDnsName { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
    public string StoredProcedureAndSchema { get; set; }
}
```

Initialise a mock storedProcedure task:

```
var storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure()
        {
            Id = 1, Description = "description", Enabled = true, Order = 1,
            JobId = 1, Job = new Job { Id = 1, Description = "description", Name = "test"}
        };
```

When I run this:

```
Log.Information("Test dec {@Task}", storedProcedure);
```

Or this:

```
Log.Information("Test dec {@Task}", (Task)storedProcedure);
```

Serilog doesn't deconstruct the object as configured.

If I use this configuration:

```
new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Destructure.ByTransforming<StoredProcedure>(t => 
                    new { TaskId = t.Id, JobId = t.JobId})
```

Serilog deconstructs the object fine, and only logs those two properties (TaskId and JobId)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the issue by using this:

```
.Destructure.ByTransformingWhere<Task>(t => typeof(Task).IsAssignableFrom(t), t => new { TaskId = t.Id, t.JobId})
```

Now this works fine:

```
var storedProcedure = new StoredProcedure()
        {
            Id = 1, Description = "description", Enabled = true, Order = 1,
            JobId = 1, Job = new Job { Id = 1, Description = "description", Name = "test"}
        };

Log.Information("Test dec {@Task}", storedProcedure);
```